# Maven wrapper can't create beans Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have a spring boot project where I have the structure like this:

```
Project:
- src
 - - module 1
 - - module 2 
 - - - Main.class
 - - - Bean.class
- pom.xml
```

I successfully can run it from IntelliJ Idea. But I wanted to test it with Maven wrapper. At first it didn't want to find a main class, I solved this problem with adding source directory:

```
<build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>module2.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

But now it doesn't want to create beans even tho from Idea it runs perfectly. What can be the problem? Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bean' defined in file [\target\classes\module2\Bean.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to ins
tantiate [module2.Bean.class]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: inStream parameter is null
```

Bean is RestController. I'm running it like this:

```
mvnw clean spring-boot:run
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project needs to respect the structure `src/main/java/{packages}`.
In your case it'll be:

```
- src
 - main
  - java
   - module 1
   - module 2
    - Main.class
    - Bean.class
- pom.xml
```

And use this plugin configuration:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```